# TeamBuild command behaviour different to running in command prompt

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, jspm

We are using TFS 2015 and trying to build a website project using NPM and JSPM.
During development we have been running "npm install" and "jspm install" from the command line when adding new packages etc, and this has worked fine.
I'm now trying to get the project building on TFS.
I have tried adding the following to the .csproj:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="attrib -r .dependencies.json" WorkingDirectory=".\jspm_packages" />
    <Exec Command="attrib -r jspm.config.js" WorkingDirectory="." />
    <Exec Command="attrib -r package.json" WorkingDirectory="." />
    <Exec Command=".bin\npm install" WorkingDirectory="." />
    <Exec Command=".bin\jspm install -y" WorkingDirectory="." />
    <Exec Command=".bin\node build.js --minify --sourceMaps" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'" WorkingDirectory="." />
  </Target>
```

and, as a separate attempt to get it working, I tried creating a .cmd file (tfsbuild.cmd):

```
attrib -r "jspm_packages\.dependencies.json"
attrib -r "jspm.config.js"
attrib -r "package.json"
call .bin\npm install > _npm.log
call .bin\jspm install -y > _jspm.log
call .bin\node build.js --minify --sourceMaps > _nodebuild.log
```

and calling that from the .csproj

```
<Exec Command="tfsbuild.cmd" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'" WorkingDirectory="." />
```

All the builds I try fail, saying that the jspm install command exited with code 1.   Note that I am feeding the output of the commands into .log files to help understand the problem.
If I run tfsbuild.cmd directly from the folder where the .csproj file ends up on the TFS build machine, then everything works correctly, and the jspm.log file output the expected response: (truncated)

```
     Creating registry cache...
ok   jquery.ui.position to npm:jquery.ui.position@^1.11.4 (1.11.4)
ok   respond.js to npm:respond.js@^1.4.2 (1.4.2)
ok   jquery2 to npm:jquery@2.2.4 (2.2.4)
ok   jquery1 to npm:jquery@1.12.3 (1.12.3)
ok   modernizr to github:Modernizr/Modernizr@2.6.2 (2.6.2)
ok   bootstrap-datetimepicker to github:smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker@2.3.9 (2.3.9)
ok   js-xlsxActual to github:sheetjs/js-xlsx@0.8.0 (0.8.0)
ok   rangy to github:timdown/rangy-release@^1.3.0 (1.3.0)
ok   jquery-validation to github:jquery-validation/jquery-validation@1.8.1 (jzaefferer/jquery-validation@1.8.1)
ok   jquery-validation-unobtrusive to github:aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive@3.2.2 (3.2.2)
ok   knockout to github:knockout/knockout@3.4.0 (3.4.0)
ok   Installed peer jsbn to npm:jsbn@0.1 (0.1.1)
ok   Installed npm:tweetnacl@^0.14.3 (0.14.5)
ok   Installed npm:chartjs-color@^2.0.0 (2.1.0)
ok   Installed npm:get-stdin@^4.0.1 (4.0.1)
ok   Installed npm:glob@^7.0.3 (7.1.1)
ok   Installed npm:lodash.mergewith@^4.6.0 (4.6.0)
ok   Installed npm:meow@^3.7.0 (3.7.0)
ok   Installed npm:lodash.clonedeep@^4.3.2 (4.5.0)
ok   Installed npm:npmlog@^4.0.0 (4.0.2)
ok   Installed npm:in-publish@^2.0.0 (2.0.0)
ok   Installed npm:cross-spawn@^3.0.0 (3.0.1)
ok   Installed npm:async-foreach@^0.1.3 (0.1.3)
ok   Installed npm:gaze@^1.0.0 (1.1.2)
...
```

However, when calling tfsbuild.cmd from the build process, the output into jspm.log is very different, and is returning code 1 to msbuild, hence the build failing. (entire file)

```
     Downloading npm:font-awesome@4.7.0
     Downloading npm:jquery@2.2.4
     Downloading npm:jquery@1.12.3
     Downloading npm:respond.js@1.4.2
     Downloading npm:emojione@2.2.7
     Downloading npm:jquery.ui.position@1.11.4

warn Installation changes not saved.
```

I am stuck as to why the commands are behaving differently when run from msbuild.   Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You are using XMAL build or Vnext build in TFS 2015?

Comment: Using MSBuild command to build the project you get down on TFS build agent sever, could it works?

Comment: We are using XAML builds.  I have now got the build working, it turned out that our jspm_packages folder in TFS didn't have everything it needed checked.  The _jspm.log is still different when kicked off through the TFS build, than when run directly through the command window.
I don't know why, but sadly don't really have the time to keep investigating

Comment: Could you please post how you solve this issue as the answer for this error and make it as the solution?